# ImpressPages admin page has 404 error

Tags: http-status-code-404, failed-installation, impresspages

I have just installed ImpressPages 4_0_17 and I completed the installation process through the point of filling out the database form and submitting it. The next page gave a 404 error on the URL /ImpressPages/admin. Prior to that, the systems check page listed 3 warnings:  Magic quotes Off, Apache mod_rewrite, PHP memory limit 64MB. No other info on these warnings was available on that page.

I am using the alias feature on GoDaddy for hosting, which allows me to create multiple websites in the same account.  In addition, I am using a sub-domain for this install so I can test it out before replacing the original site. Because I uploaded the entire IP zip file and extracted it in the web root folder, all the IP files are now installed in the folder /ImpressPages.

After the 404 error, I altered the URL to be just /ImpressPages/.  That actually loaded fine.  In addition, a small dialog popped up saying that I had been automatically logged in as admin.  It gave me the username, password and the email I configured for the site.  It also provided the admin page URL that produces a 404 error and said I needed to go there to login in the future.

The home page at /ImpressPages/ loads and shows inline editing features. If I click the Lorem Ipsum link, /ImpressPages/index.php/lorem-ipsumy, I get a white page with the one line:

"No input file specified."

I have tried a few tweaks to the .htaccess file with no success. The latest active lines are shown below. All the other lines from the default file are commented out and I have not tried messing with them.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

# Attempt to fix SVG images, 6/4/2014
    AddType image/svg+xml svg
    AddType image/svg+xml svgz

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ImpressPages/index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

#    Redirect www urls to non-www.
#    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
#    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

The changes I attempted to get admin access are in the RewriteRule. I prefixed index.php first with a slash, then with /ImpressPages/.  Neither one helped.  Any suggestions on how to get admin access will be greatly appreciated.

17:11 - New info:
With the /ImpressPages/ path and the following .htaccess lines enabled, I can now get the login dialog on the admin page. Once I enter the login correctly, the next URL is /ImpressPages/index.php with the white page described previously. Then reloading /ImpressPages/admin produces the same white page and the same /ImpressPages/index.php URL. So now I can login, but it doesn't help.

```
Options -Indexes
Options -MultiViews
```

Those lines are in the default .htaccess file already. I just removed the comment character to activate them.

17:45 - more progress.
I moved all the contents of the /ImpressPages/ folder up one level to web root. Then I removed /ImpressPages/ from the path for index.php in the rewrite rule. With that one change, admin login started working and I am now able to edit my site. There are still issues. For example, publishing a page does publish the changes, but then loads the typical white page with the URL /index.php/home.  The URL / loads the home page correctly.  Almost sounds like the URL routing is not working correctly.

Comment: We will try to register on Go Daddy to see the problem on our own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like ImpressPages instal decided your server doesn't support URL rewrites and has placed rewritesDisabled in config.php

Try to remove this config line.

Comment: Yes, that was the solution. Thank you.